# [Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Firestore backend

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have configured Firebase/Firestore, but Firestore return this error ever:

> [Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Firestore backend.

I'm using Swift 4 and Xcode 9. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update 10th March 2018 - thanks to richardfrk

This issue has now been fixed in Firebase SDK 4.10.1

---

Unfortunately I experienced this bug yesterday for Firebase SDK 4.10.0 and have reported it directly to one of the Firebase engineers working on the iOS SDK. For me, I only had this error when the user is not authenticated. As soon as the user is authenticated, the problem went away.

For now, I'd recommend sticking with Firebase SDK 4.9.0 until they fix it in the next update.

Comment: ohhhh, I spent half day yesterday with this sh**t!! That's the reason we should use a fixed version in podfile! even while you developing. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Wow guy! This problem is solved. I upgrade version to 4.10.1 and its solved. Tks bro.

Comment: Wow. Thank man. It was HUGE!! I'm so glad they fixed quickly. It's working fine.

Comment: me too with 4.10.1