# React Native Firestore - Could not reach Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently having an issues where Firebase is failing to connect in a React Native app on iOS (Android app connects fine).

Here's the error I'm seeing in Xcode:

```
4.11.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Firestore backend.
```

And the currently installed Firebase Pods:

```
Firebase (4.11.0)   
FirebaseAnalytics (4.1.0)   
FirebaseAuth (4.5.0)   
FirebaseCore (4.0.18)   
FirebaseFirestore (0.10.4)   
FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10)   
FirebaseMessaging (2.1.1)   
FirebaseStorage (2.1.3)
```

It sounds like there was a similar issue that was addressed with the 4.10.1 release of the Firebase SDK ([[Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Firestore backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177204/firestorei-fst000001-could-not-reach-firestore-backend))

Anyone else seeing this error on 4.11.0?

Comment: I personally don’t like those 3rd party libraries which provides you with the native bridge to use. I think the most flexible option would be to implement your needs in native and bridge it by your self or you checkout the module, make it work natively and include your repo url to the package.json.

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem with Firestore (4.10.1): app on iOS device connects but the one on Android emulator does not.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: My answer ended up being an oversight. We recently updated our apps bundle id which I changed on the Android project in the Firebase Console but not on the iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

This problem ended up being an oversight on my part. I had a different bundle ID specified in the Firebase Console than what my project was set to. Here's a quick way to check that it matches.

**iOS**

In the *GoogleServices-Info.plist* file that you've added to your iOS project, there's a "BUNDLE_ID" key. The value of that key should match the Bundle Identifier field in Xcode under the General tab of your project.

**Android**

In your React Native project, navigate to *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*. Verify that the manifest->package attribute matches what's in your *google-services.json* file under client_info->android_client_info->package_name.

Comment: Hi, I know it a bit old question but I'm getting the same error it works for iOS but on android, it shows the same error you were getting. I haven't made separate iOS and Android projects but instead, I have one project for the web and I'm using its keys to implement both. Any suggestions?